# "Would he be the voice of reason?"

Tags: grammar, grammar-myths

Is this grammatically correct sentence? I cannot seem to understand the grammar behind the structure of this sentence

So if we change "would" to "why", it seems incorrect to me to say

> "why he is the voice of reason?"

It seems more natural to say

> "why is he the voice of reason?"

so if I apply the same pattern to "would", it makes more sense to me to say

> "Would be he the voice of reason?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you change a statement into a question, the subject and the auxiliary must switch places.

> Statement: *He is* the voice of reason 
> Question: Why *is he* the voice of reason

This phenomenon is known as the [subject-auxiliary inversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion). One thing to note about the subject-auxiliary inversion is that only the subject and **the first auxiliary** are involved.

The sentence below has two auxiliaries: "would" and "be". So only the first auxiliary ("would") is fronted; "be" should remain in-situ:

> Statement: *He would* be the voice of reason 
> Question: *Would he* be the voice of reason?

The sentence below is therefore ungrammatical:

> *Would be he the voice of reason?